# Use EditText from main.xml in my onReceive

Tags: android, android-layout, broadcastreceiver, alarm

I have an AlarmActivity with main.xml layout. And an alarm class that extends BroadcastReceive and a method onReceive. I want to get the value from EditText in main.xml into my onReceive method in the alarm class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't keep that value in SharedPreference and fetch it in Receiver...  A reliable way to do... The current approach fails since you never know whether the Activity holding EditText lives or not..

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you understand how a BroadcastReceiever works. Its Asynchronus, meaning that an Activity may not be up at that time, but you can launch something given the BroadcastReciever's Context. Change your approach.